# position absolute rendering the button in a new line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div that contains the 2 buttons side by side and I want that div to move around by using the top and left properties but unfortunately when I apply the position: absolute the button is rendering in the new line. I don't want that button to appear in a new line when position: absolute to it. thanks in advance.

```css
.btn-primary{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 7% 0px 5px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image:linear-gradient(#25cdf7, #1144ab);;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .btn-text{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

```html
 <div>
    <a class="btn-primary"><h6 class="btn-text">Subject</h6><h5 class="btn-text">PHYSICS</h5></a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
    <a class="btn-primary" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#4cad4e,#4cad4e); "><h6 class="btn-text">Topic</h6><h5 class="btn-text">FORCES</h5></a>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23zqfpt0/)

Comment: what is the output you want?

Comment: same output with `position:absolute` to that div

Comment: add dislay: flex to the div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the same in 2 ways.

1. Just give that div `white-space:nowrap;`
2. give it the min-width so both the buttons can fit in, As the
   absolute positioned item do not carry its width, you need to mention
   it.

```css
.btn-primary{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 7% 0px 5px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image:linear-gradient(#25cdf7, #1144ab);;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .btn-text{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
    div {position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 100px; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="btn-primary"><h6 class="btn-text">Subject</h6><h5 class="btn-text">PHYSICS</h5></a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
    <a class="btn-primary" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#4cad4e,#4cad4e); "><h6 class="btn-text">Topic</h6><h5 class="btn-text">FORCES</h5></a>
  </div>
```

second option:

```css
.btn-primary{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 7% 0px 5px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image:linear-gradient(#25cdf7, #1144ab);;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .btn-text{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
    div {position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 100px; min-width: 500px;}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="btn-primary"><h6 class="btn-text">Subject</h6><h5 class="btn-text">PHYSICS</h5></a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
    <a class="btn-primary" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#4cad4e,#4cad4e); "><h6 class="btn-text">Topic</h6><h5 class="btn-text">FORCES</h5></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: it shouldn't affect the width of the buttons as well. I don't want to reduce the width

Comment: edited, either use min-width or width 100% on the div, I would suggest using min-width

Answer (score 0):

Apply `width:100%` like

```
.box{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}



<div class="box">
    <a class="btn-primary"><h6 class="btn-text">Subject</h6><h5 class="btn-text">PHYSICS</h5></a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
    <a class="btn-primary" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#4cad4e,#4cad4e); "><h6 class="btn-text">Topic</h6><h5 class="btn-text">FORCES</h5></a>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/vbLxk9w8/1/

Answer (score 0):

In responsive terms you can position the button absolutely where you want it. `Position:absolute` will automatically change the location of the element, but it's just a matter of using `margin-left/right` and/or `top/bottom` in conjunction with `%`to adjust the layout. This will make it `position:absolute` and browser/device responsive.

For example:

```
.foo {position:absolute; top: 50%; margin-bottom: 25px;}
```

should create absolute positioning across devices and this can be infinitely adjusted with `top/bottom` amd `margin`, positive or negative. PX without `%`can be read as relative value, whereas `%` will often define itself as an absolute value across devices/browsers. `top: 200px;` of one screen size will often be placed higher or lower in relation to another screen size, even when `position:absolute;` is applied.